# What is $Spec(\mathbb{Z}[x])$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

What is $Spec(\mathbb{Z}[x])$? For a commutative ring $A$ e with $1$, its spectrum $Spec(A)$ is defined to be the set of all of its prime ideals. So the question is to find all the prime ideals of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Try to find the treasure map laid out by Mumford. (If you don't know what this means, try to google)

Comment: Do you mean the red book?

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much, you give me an answer!